# 500 Internal Server Error in django static files on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache-2.2, centos

Recently I deployed a Django powered application but I have some problem with static files. Sometimes (and only sometimes), I get **500 Internal Server Error** in getting static files such as css/js/image. Please take look at this images:

First request:

[image]

Second:

[image: Second request]

and last request:

[image: First request]

You can see that in three separate requests, I got different result in static files.

Apache Log:

```
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view, referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs), referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 32, in server_error, referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93]     t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template., referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template, referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93]     template, origin = find_template(template_name), referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template, referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93]     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name), referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
[Wed Oct 10 16:00:08 2012] [error] [client 37.98.23.93] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html, referer: http://mydomain.biz/static/style/main.css
```

I have Apache 2.* and Django 1.4.1 with Python 2.6 on CentOS 5.

Comment: Is there anything in your apache logs that might give a little more indication?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: As it says in the logs, first you need to create a 500.html template. Once you've done that, you should be emailed a traceback with the real problem, if you have correctly set `ADMINS` in your settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved but I don't know why. Previously, I used this route for static files:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

and after set this custom route, everything is fine:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/home/path_to/static'}),
)
```

Comment: good job, you must be look at this page http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/10-insanely-useful-django-tips/